# showing only one of parameters read from url using curl

Tags: php-curl

I'm using this curl get request

```
    <?php
$ch = curl_init("https://currency.jafarili.me/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

and i only need to echo
{"Name":"Gold 18","Rate":"1054988"}
this line Rate number only. now I'm echoing all of the content from here.
how should I change the code?
I'm very new to php I will really appreciate if anyone could help me. thx.

ok I found how to do this. this is the correct code

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://currency.jafarili.me/json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->Item[2]->Rate;

?>
```

Comment: ok I found how to do this.

Comment: <?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://currency.jafarili.me/json');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->Item[2]->Rate;

?>

this is how i did it